# Ruby wrong result durning vectors calculations

Tags: ruby, math, vector

We are trying to implement "[Calculating coefficients of interpolating polynomial using Neville's algorithm](https://github.com/Nemeczek/Metody.Neville)."

This is our Vector Class:

```
class Wektor < Array
  attr_accessor :coordinatesAmount

  def initialize(length)
    super(length, 0)
    @coordinatesAmount = length
  end

  def SetVector(w)
    for i in (0...coordinatesAmount) do
      self[i] = w[i]
    end
    return self
  end

  def MultiplyBy(n)
    for i in (0...coordinatesAmount) do
      self[i] *= n      
    end
    return self
  end

  def DivideBy(n)
    for i in (0...coordinatesAmount) do
      self[i] /= n
    end
    return self
  end

  def Sub(w)
    for i in (0...coordinatesAmount) do
      self[i] -= w[i]
    end
    return self
  end

  def Add(w)
    for i in (0...coordinatesAmount) do
      self[i] += w[i]
    end
    return self
  end

  def ShiftRight
    coordinatesAmount.downto(1) { |i|
      self[i-1] = self[i-2]
    }
    self[0] = 0
    return self
  end
```

This is our calculation part:

```
require_relative 'wektor.rb'
#Coefficients

def Coefficients(i, j, tabX, tabY, pyramid)
  #mnozymy przez Xj
  length = pyramid[i][j-1].length

  temp = Wektor.new(length).SetVector(pyramid[i][j-1])
  temp.MultiplyBy(tabX[j])
  pyramid[i][j].SetVector(temp)

  #odjęcie Pi,j-1 przesuniętego o 1 w prawo
  temp = Wektor.new(length).SetVector(pyramid[i][j-1])
  temp.ShiftRight
  pyramid[i][j].Sub(temp)

  #dodanie Pi+1, j przesuniętego o 1 w prawo
  temp = Wektor.new(length).SetVector(pyramid[i+1][j])
  temp.ShiftRight
  pyramid[i][j].Add(temp)

  #odjęcie Pi+1, j pomnożonego przez Xi
  temp = Wektor.new(length).SetVector(pyramid[i+1][j])
  temp.MultiplyBy(tabX[i])
  pyramid[i][j].Sub(temp)

  #podzielenie przez (Xj - Xi)
  pyramid[i][j].DivideBy(tabX[j] - tabX[i])

  return pyramid[i][j]
end

#CalculateResult 
def CalculatePolynomialResult(x,y,n)
  pyramid = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Wektor.new(n)}

  for i in 0...n do
      for j in 0...n-i do
          if (j != i+j) then
              next
          end

          pyramid[j][j] = Wektor.new(n)
          pyramid[j][j].push(y[j])
      end
  end

  for i in 0...n do
      for j in 0...n-i do
          if (j == i+j) then
              next
          end

          pyramid[j][i+j] = Wektor.new(n)
          Coefficients(j, i+j, x, y, pyramid)
      end
  end

  return pyramid[0][n-1]

end
```

We are facing the problem when the Coefficients method is calculating something we still get zeros. There is no exception error but our Vector are zeros. I added a link for our Source at Math Overflow to explain what is going on.

This is [the same code but written in C#](https://github.com/Nemeczek/Metody.Neville), to play with .NET.

Any ideas why our vectors are useless? Like something is overwriting them or maybe with some value/reference? We are unable to track that issue.

Comment: "we still get zeros".  Where exactly?  That method is long, is it a zero inside it that is the problem?  The result is zero?  Do you have tests you are running to get these zeroes?  Can we see what you're doing to run this?  Example input and expected output usually nets lots of help here.

Comment: Give a simple example, your current code is a bit too convoluted to give any real help. Also, note that your code isn't very idiomatic. It appears that you are trying to write Ruby in the style of a less expressive language.

Comment: In Ruby we name methods using snake_case, not CamelCase. Instead of `for i in (0...coordinatesAmount)` look at using `coordinates_amount.times ...`, or better, take advantage of the fact you're sub-classing Array and iterate over the arrays using `map`. Your code will be simpler.

Comment: And we usually name `multiply_by`, `divide_by`, `sub`, `add`, `shift_right`, and `set_vector` as `*`, `/`, `-`, `+`, `>>`, and `vector=`, although a `Vector` *really* should be a value type and not have setters *at all*. (In particular, it absolutely should *not* have the `coordinatesAmount=` setter. Which is a terrible name anyway, it should be called `dimension` instead.) Also, a `Vector` is much more like a number than an array, and thus should instead extend `Numeric`, not `Array` and implement the proper `coerce` protocol.

Comment: you could use a '#' at the 'require_relative 'wektor.rb'' so it will be '#require_relative 'wektor.rb''

Comment: you also need an 'end' at the of your vector class